# Spirit forum in Django

Tags: django, django-haystack

Can anybody here help to to run spirit as a new Django project, I want to run that but there is no manage file. And there is no guide how to run the spirit forum as stand alone project.

If anybody please provide a video or screenshot to setup the spirit it will be very helpful.
I tried a lot but I failed so I am asking for help

Related links:

http://spirit-project.com
https://github.com/nitely/Spirit

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spirit is just another Django app. You just have to install it, put it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, import the urlconf and make other configuration changes as necessary.

They have included an example here: https://github.com/nitely/Spirit/tree/master/example

Check out the README file there and try yourself. If you're stuck on any step, please ask the specific question, will try to help.